# how to replace \$ with $ in regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String

```
String valueExpression = "value1\\$\\$bla";
```

i would like it to be parsed to:

```
value1$$bla
```

when I try to do:

```
valueExpression.replaceAll("\\\\$", "\\$");
```

I get it the same, and when I try to do:

```
valueExpression.replaceAll("\\$", "$");
```

I get an error IndexOutOfBound

How can I replace it in regex?

The string is dynamic so I can't change the content of the string valueExpression to something static.

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape the dash twice, one for Java and once for the regex. You also need to escape the dollar sign. This makes 6 dashes and a dollar sign.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)): "Note that backslashes (\\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different". Two on two, good job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valueExpression.replaceAll("\\\\[$]", "\\$");` should achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest approach seems to be

```
valueExpression.replace("\\$", "$")
```

which is similar to

```
valueExpression.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\$"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("$"))
```

which means that it automatically escapes all regex matacharacters from both parts (*target* and *replacement*) letting you use simple literals.

BTW lets not forget that String is **immutable** so its methods like `replace` can't change its state (can't change characters it stores) but will create new String with replaced characters.
So you want to use

```
valueExpression = valueExpression.replace("\\$", "$");
```

---

Example:

```
String valueExpression = "value1\\$\\$bla";
System.out.println(valueExpression.replace("\\$", "$"));
```

output: `value1$$bla`

Comment: Can I see how you are using this method? Also knowing what kind of exception you are getting could be useful to correct your code.

Answer (score 0):

You want a string containing `\\\$` (double backslash to get a literal backslash, and a backslash to escape the `$`). To write that quoted as a string in Java you should escape each backslash with another backslash. So you would write that as `"\\\\\\$"`.

Ie.

```
valueExpression.replaceAll("\\\\\\$", "\\$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use direct string replacement:

`valueExpression.replace("\\$", "$");`

or you need to escape group reference in the replacement string:

`valueExpression.replaceAll("\\$", "\\$");`